# Two properties of the set of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, bernoulli-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). We are looking for an answer for
one of the following (or both) questions.

**(a)** Is there an **infinite** subset $S$ of **rationals**  such that
$(\mathcal{B}-\mathcal{B})\cap (S-S)=\{ 0\}$?

**(b)**  Is it true that $(\mathcal{B}-\mathcal{B})+F\neq \mathbb{Q}$, for every **finite** subset  $F$ of rationals?

Note that $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$ and  $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A , b\in B\}$.

Also, $(\mathcal{B}-\mathcal{B})\cap (S-S)=\{ 0\}$ is equivalent to the property that every element $x$ of  $\mathcal{B}+S$ has a unique
representation $x=b+s$ with $b\in \mathcal{B}$ and $s\in S$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both questions is yes.

---

The [von Staudt-Clausen theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonStaudt-ClausenTheorem.html) implies that the denominators of Bernoulli numbers $B$ are square-free. Notice that [Rational numbers with square-free denominators make a subgroup of $\mathbb Q$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_rational_numbers_with_square-free_denominators), so a group generated by $B$ would be a subgroup of that subgroup, which means denominators of nonzero elements of $(B- B)$ are square-free.

Then for example, $S=\{1/p^2:p\text{ is odd prime}\}$ answers **(a)** because denominators of nonzero elements of $(S-S)$ are odd squares (of semiprimes).

---

For **(b)** assume the opposite, that there exists finite $F$ such that $(B-B)+F=\mathbb Q$.

Since $F$ is finite there exits a $k$ such that for all primes $p$, prime power $p^k$ does not divide any denominators in $F$. Recall that $(B-B)$ is square-free (denominators are not divisible by $p^n,n\gt 1$). It follows that denominators of elements in $(B-B)+F$ are divisible by at most $p^{k-1}\cdot p^1=p^k$, i.e. are not divisible by $p^{k+1}$.

That is, $1/p^{k+1}\not\in((B-B)+F)\subset\mathbb Q$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: -@Vepir. Many thanks for your interesting answer. Could you please explain the reason for $S\subseteq F$.

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand I've removed that argument and added a better one, I hope it is clear now. In essence, the exponents of primes that make up the denominators are bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your time.